# Como deixar mensagens de usuários em lados diferentes no chat?

Tags: php, css

Estou desenvolvendo um chat usando PHP, MySQL e jQuery.

Minha dúvida é como posso fazer com que a mensagem dos usuários fiquem um pra cada lado para diferenciar?

Segue o código PHP:

```
             echo "
                <div class=\"row msg_container base_sent\">
                    <div class=\"col-md-10 col-xs-10\">
                        <div class=\"messages msg_sent\">
                            <p style=\"color: #303030\">$mensagem</p>
                            <time datetime=\"2009-11-13T20:00\" style=\"color: #303030\">$nick - $newHora</time>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class=\"col-md-2 col-xs-2 avatar\">
                        <img src=\"http://www.bitrebels.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Original-Facebook-Geek-Profile-Avatar-1.jpg\" class=\"img-responsive\">
                    </div>
                </div>";
```

Acredito que a imagem pode ajudar a compreender o que eu quero:

[image: Ten]

Comment: Use CSS. Para mais informações, edite sua pergunta e coloque os códigos HTML e CSS. Não coloque o código da página inteira, apenas o que é relativo ao problema, mas foque em elaborar um [mcve].

Comment: Acho que você esqueceu de ler o que é um [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

```js
let mensagens = [
    {
        'mensagem': 'Olá',
        'status': 0
    },
    {
        'mensagem': 'Olá, Tudo bem?',
        'status': 1
    },
    {
        'mensagem': 'Tudo e você?',
        'status': 0
    },
    {
        'mensagem': 'Como vai a familia?',
        'status': 0
    },
    {
        'mensagem': 'Por aqui tudo está bem tambem',
        'status': 1
    },
];

mensagens.map(val => {
    console.log(val)
    if(val.status == 0){
        $('.chat').append('<span class="msgLeft">'+val.mensagem+'</span>')
    }else{
        $('.chat').append('<span class="msgRight">'+val.mensagem+'</span>')
    }

})
```

```css
.chat{
    background: #F5F5F5;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
}

.chat .msgLeft{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}

.chat .msgRight{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    text-align: right
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chat">

</div>
```

Pra isso você pode utilizar CSS e JS. Segue um exemplo de como faria

CSS

```
.chat{
    background: #F5F5F5;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
}

.chat .msgLeft{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}

.chat .msgRight{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    text-align: right
}
```

Javascript

```
let mensagens = [
    {
        'mensagem': 'Olá',
        'status': 0
    },
    {
        'mensagem': 'Olá, Tudo bem?',
        'status': 1
    },
    {
        'mensagem': 'Tudo e você?',
        'status': 0
    },
    {
        'mensagem': 'Como vai a familia?',
        'status': 0
    },
    {
        'mensagem': 'Por aqui tudo está bem tambem',
        'status': 1
    },
];

mensagens.map(val => {
    console.log(val)
    if(status == 0){
        $('.chat').append('<span class="msgLeft">'+val.mensagem+'</span>')
    }else{
        $('.chat').append('<span class="msgRight">'+val.mensagem+'</span>')
    }

})
```

HTML

Lembrando que é só um exemplo, você terá que adaptar conforme sua necessidade.

Pode ver funcionando [aqui](https://jsbin.com/nufitol/edit?html,js,console,output)